# Table of contents in vi(m)

Tags: vim

I find using markers to be very efficient in vim. However, if the markers is ever greater than 3 or so, it's difficult for me to remember them.

Is it possible to set up something like a table of contents in vim. For example, a list of functions at the top of a python file and clicking them goes to that marker? One option I thought of is folding the code, but I would like the code un-folded always, and just be able to easily navigate between functions by either clicking/pressing enter on the TOC/bookmark at the top.

Is anything like that possible in vim? Perhaps this question boils down to, is it possible to have something like an "anchor" in vim (a clickable link that takes you to a marker), so that I could do something like:

```
[def my_method()](`'a`)
```

And clicking the `def my_method()` would go to `ma` ?

Comment: You'd better look for a plugin (tagbar?).

Comment: @Matt or even just tags themselves... if the language is well supported, universal ctags generally gives me enough of the « jump-around » functionality that regular vim stuff doesnt have

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, of course, that's very possible. However OP asked exactly for "a clickable link". And this is basically what tagbar adds on top of ctags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global command to see where some patterns are:

```
:g/.*def\s\w\+(/

.* ................ anything
def ............... function definition
\s ................ space
\w\+ .............. words
```

This will show you each function definition with line number

Comment: yea, not now I'm just doing a `*` or `#` on one of the `def`s and it does the same thing. But a bit tedious jumping down 20 functions or so.